# How to count total number of option of drop-down in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am trying to verify number of options of drop-down but it is not working. I have used the following code:

```
campaignManagementPage.statusDropDown().Count();
this.statusDropDown = function () {
    return element(by.model('campaign.lifeStage'));
}
```

HTML for drop down is following:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-ng- model="campaign.lifeStage">
    <option value="design">Design</option>
    <option value="preview">Preview</option>
    <option value="live">Live</option>
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a separate field in your page object:

```
this.statusDropDownItems = function () {
    return element.all('select.form-control option');
}
```

or relying on the model and chaining `element` and `element.all`:

```
this.statusDropDownItems = function () {
    return element(by.model('campaign.lifeStage')).element.all('option');
}
```

Then, in your test spec you can use `expect` to assert the count:

```
expect(page.statusDropDownItems.count()).toEqual(4);
```

where `page` is your Page Object instance.

Comment: Thanks alecxe . I want to do more Can you please tell me how to verify the first option text is design

Comment: @RashmiChauhan it should be `expect(page.statusDropDownItems.first().getText()).toEqual("Design");`